# Is there a function such that the $n^{th}$ derivative equals the $n^{th}$ power of the first derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have seen functions whose second derivative is equal to the square of the first derivative. So is there a function whose $n^{th}$  derivative is equal to the $n^{th}$ power of the first derivative. Or, is there a function such that -

$$\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^n=\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}$$

Comment: this is just an ode.. $y^{(n)} - (y')^n = 0$

Comment: Note that any constant function works.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ The closest other functions I can think of are exponential functions. They don't satisfy the equation, but they're pretty close to.

Comment: WA [can't solve it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27-(y%27)%5E3%3D0) even for $n=3$...

Comment: Did you want this to be true for all $n$, or just a given $n$?

Comment: @BrianTung Preferably all n. I am aware of a few functions which satisfy the above equation only when n =2.

Comment: Well, a solution for *any* given $n$ is better than nothing... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(x) = -((n-1)!)^{1/(n-1)} \ln(x)$ is a solution.

Comment: How did you find that? That's quite amazing.

Comment: Like @BadrB, I too would like at least a general story for how you found this.

Comment: @Somos: I think that is an error in the edit by Parcly Taxel.  That previously read $-[(n-1)!]^\frac{1}{n-1}\ln x$, and the $(n-1)!$ was replaced by $\Gamma(x)$, rather than $\Gamma(n)$.  (Note that $n$ is presumed to be an integer, so the expression did not need to be made continuous.)  I'm going to revert the edit.

Comment: @obertIsrael can you please tell us how you arrived at that solution or did you know this before?

Comment: If $y = f'$, the equation says $y^n = y^{(n-1)}$.  Constant times a power of $x$ is an obvious thing to try...